# How to de-duplicate email addresses in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, duplicate-management

I am trying to send emails through journey builder but if a person has multiple accounts with the same email address, I only want them to receive one email. I've tried this exclusion script:

```
%%[
    RowCount(LookupRows("JB-Test", "Email Address", emailaddr)) > 1
]%%
```

But it doesn't send any email if there is duplicate email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set the email address as primary key in the data extension of the journey's entry event.

> Primary Key - Determines whether the system considers this field to be the primary key of the table.
>   If you select this checkbox, the system requires that the value in this field be unique so it can use this field to uniquely identify a row. If you select this checkbox for more than one column, then the combination of the values in the columns must be unique.
>   If you do not select this checkbox, the system does not require the value in this field to be unique.
> (Source: [Create a Data Extension](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_new_data_extension/))

For completeness sake even if this might not work in your setup as the filter is by subscriber key and not by email address: Another possibility is setting the journey re-entry settings to "No re-entry". However this only works per journey version and filters out by subscriber key.

> Select No re-entry if contacts cannot enter the journey again after a previous entry. This setting applies across all versions of a journey.  Once you activate the journey, you cannot change this option.
> (Source: [Journey Settings](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/))

**Related documentation:**

- [Journey Settings](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/)
- [Create a Data Extension](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_new_data_extension/)

Comment: I thought about that but there are some emails that I want them to get multiple of. For example: the person is a parent with two children, so they would have three accounts associated with the parent email. I would want the parent to only receive one "Welcome" email but I would want the parent to receive a birthday email for each child on their birthdays.

Comment: That should be two different journeys so there is no problem with that.

Comment: @MarkusSlabina I've been trying to use your solution, but the JB DE doesn't let me change the structure, screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/5nMj518 - any thoughts? This is a welcome journey using Sales Cloud campaign. It's three consecutive emails and I need to figure out how to eliminate Leads who might might be duplicates (same email, different IDs)

Comment: @CodeRage For Sales Cloud entry events this is a bit trickier, as you cannot change the data extension configuration. You need to either solve this problem within Sales Cloud or filter the contacts in your journey. For example, you could add exit criteria based on a data extension you fill with the email addresses and link to your data model, etc. Another way, that only suppresses emails but lets the leads through your journey would be writing a simple exclusion script.

Comment: @MarkusSlabina I tried a variety of exclusion scripts, including using a set of data extensions to mark which email address got which email out of the three, but with three different consecutive emails in one journey it's really hard - do you have any suggestions how the script could look like? Here's my journey: https://imgur.com/a/dskhcvc